# How to play two media through different audio devices with MPV?

Tags: macos, media-player, mpv

How can I use MPV to play a video file with audio through one audio device (built-in speakers), and a second audio file through a second audio device (bluetooth headphones).

Play/pause should play/pause both media at the same time.

I have found ways to play audio via different devices on command line using ffmpeg, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f audiotoolbox 1
```

plays on my bluetooth headphones and

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f audiotoolbox 3
```

plays on the built-in speakers even when bluetooth headphones are connected.

I have found some ways to combine streams in mpv, e.g.

```
mpv --lavfi-complex="[aid1][aid2]amix[ao]" video.mp4 --external-files=audio.mp3
```

plays both audio streams at the same time in MPV (and keeps them synced) on top of the video.

But I don't know how to send one audio to bluetooth headphones and the other audio to speakers.

Comment: One app has one audio path. You'd need two separate apps.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you mean that MPV is designed so that it can only output all of its audio to one device?

Comment: Any app [on any platform] that can handle an audio stream has one output. The only things that don't are dedicated DAWs, specialised audio multitrack apps, which require specialist driver setups.